# How to configure kube-proxy bind IP address?

Tags: proxy, kubernetes

For testing purposes, I want to set up the kubernetes master to be only accessible from the local machine and not the outside. Ultimately I am going to run a proxy server docker container on the machine that is opened up to the outside. This is all inside a minikube VM.

I figure configuring kube-proxy is the way to go. I did the following

```
kubeadm config view > ~/cluster.yaml
# edit proxy bind address
vi ~/cluster.yaml
kubeadm reset
rm -rf /data/minikube
kubeadm init --config cluster.yaml
```

Upon doing `netstat -ln | grep 8443` i see `tcp        0      0 :::8443                 :::*                    LISTEN` which means it didn't take the IP.

I have also tried `kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address 127.0.0.1` but that only changes the advertised address to 10.x.x.x in the `kubeadm config view`. I feel that is probably the wrong thing anyways. I don't want the API server to be inaccessible to the other docker containers that need to access it or something.

I have also tried doing this `kubeadm config upload from-file --config ~/cluster.yaml` and then attempting to manually restart the docker running kube-proxy.
Also tried to restart the machine/cluster after kubeadm config change but couldn't figure that out. When you reboot a minikube VM by hand kubeadm command disappears and not even docker is running. Various online methods of restarting things dont seem to work either (could be just doing this wrong).

Also tried editing the kube-proxy docker's config file (bound to a local dir) but that gets overwritten when i restart the docker. I dont get it.

There's nothing in the kubernetes dashboard that allows me to edit the config file of the kube-proxy either (since its a daemonset).

Ultimately, I wish to use an authenticated proxy server sitting infront of the k8s master (apiserver specifically). Direct access to the k8s master from outside the VM will not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you could limit it via the local network configuration. (Firewall, Routes)
As far as I know, the API needs to be accessible, at least via the local network where the other nodes reside in. Except you want to have a single node "cluster".

So, when you do not have a different network card, where you could advertise or bind the address to, you need to limit it then by the above mentioned Firewall or Route rules.

To your initial question topic, did you look into this issue? https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/39586

Comment: I mentioned that changing API server bind address is probably the wrong approach anyways. When you bind it to 127.0.0.1 it goes to a 10.x.x.x internal address in the config instead of the machine IP, but you can still get to it from the machine's IP (outside the VM). I figured this is because of kube-proxy, which I cant seem to configure properly.